# Scrolling of Tableview is crashing the Monotouch based iOS App

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin

Hi i am right now developing a custom cell based tableview by using Monotouch.

The table view is showing data properly in custom cell.

But when i tried to scroll the table view, it is crashing the app.

**Error Message:-**

```
MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown. 

 Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason:
 -[__NSCFSet tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfd50430
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
  at OrderManagementSystem.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/administrator/Documents/xyz/dlds/OMS/OMS/Main.cs:17
```

Also i am not able to catch the method where it is crashing even though i enable the breakpoint.

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Beside the code could you tell us which version(s) of iOS is being used ? is it only on the simulator, device(s) or both ?

Comment: Looks like the tableview datasource is getting messed up - take a look at that/post it up here.